# Mercurial(TurtoiseHG) .hgrc file error

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I try to set up .hgrc file:

```
[ui]
username = MyName MySecondName <mymail@gmail.com>
```

I placed it under С:/Users/myusername/.hgrc
WHen I try

```
hg commit
```

or just

```
hg
```

I get following:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like your configuration file starts with a UTF-8 BOM (`0xEF 0xBB 0xBF`). Removing that should fix the problem for starters, but might result in errors because AFAIK `.hgrc` is supposed to be in the default locale charset (not UTF-8).

Comment: That was it! Clicked "Convert to UTF-8 without BOM" in Notepad++.

Comment: You're now honor bound to send an email to the notepad++ developer and tell him or her that putting binary crap at the front of text files is an abomination.  It's the law. ;)

Comment: @Mighter - just interesting: why do you have pure ANSI (?) file in UTF8?

Comment: I guess that's default encoding in my Notepad++ and I'm too illiterate to see the problem :)